# Python Tkinter Ventana que Cambia de Color cada cierto tiempo

Tags: python, tkinter

Lo que pasa es que hice una ventana en Tkinter que cambie de color el Root y el Frame con el metodo After y este funciona al ejecutarse la Ventana2 este empieza a cambiar de color, pero pasados unos segundos se queda colgada la ventana y termina crasehando osea se queda congelada y ya no cierra ni nada, me toca desde el administrador de tares o darle a cerrar y esperar, entonces no se que es lo que pasa, soy medio novato en Tkinter y hasta ahora uso el metodo After.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter.font import BOLD
from tkinter import messagebox
class Ventanas:
def Ventana(self):
    self.Root=Tk()
    Nombre=StringVar()
    self.Root.title("Misión Tic 2022")
    self.Root.geometry("390x220")
    self.Root.config(relief=RIDGE)
    self.Root.config(bd=45)
    self.Root.config(bg="Salmon")
    self.Frame=Frame()
    self.Frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    LabelTitulo=Label(self.Frame, text="Bienvenido a Misión Tic 2022", font=BOLD)
    LabelTitulo.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
    LabelNombre=Label(self.Frame, text="Digite Aqui su Nombre:", pady=20, padx=20)
    LabelNombre.grid(row=1, column=0)
    EntryNombre=Entry(self.Frame, textvariable=Nombre)
    EntryNombre.grid(row=1, column=1)
    BotonEnvio=Button(self.Frame, text="Enviar", command=M.Enviar)
    BotonEnvio.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
    self.Root.mainloop()
def Enviar(self):
    Pregunta1=messagebox.askokcancel("Felicidades", "Felicidades por entrar a Misión Tic 2022")
    if Pregunta1==True:
        Pregunta2=messagebox.askokcancel("Espera", "Espera por lo que se viene")
    if Pregunta2==True:
        self.Pregunta3=messagebox.askokcancel("Sigue...", "Estas cerca")
    if self.Pregunta3==True:
        self.Root.destroy()
        M.Ventana2()
def Ventana2(self):
    self.Root2=Tk()
    self.Root2.config(bg="Black")
    self.Root2.config(bd=45)
    self.Root2.config(relief=SUNKEN)
    self.Root2.geometry("500x500")
    self.Frame2=Frame()
    self.Frame2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    self.Frame2.config(bg="Lime")
    self.Frame2.config(bd=45)
    self.Frame2.config(width=250, height=350)
    self.Frame2.config(relief=GROOVE)
    self.Frames2=Frame(self.Frame2)
    self.Frames2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    self.Frames2.config(bg="White")
    self.Frames2.config(bd=25)
    self.Frames2.config(width=100, height=100)
    self.Frames2.config(relief=GROOVE)
    LabelResultado=Label(self.Frames2, text="Aqui va el Texto")
    LabelResultado.place(x=100, y=100)
    M.CambioColor()
    self.Root2.mainloop()
def CambioColor(self):
    Colores=["Blue", "Red", "Pink", "Orange", "Yellow", "Purple", "Brown", "Lime", "White", "Cyan"]
    random_colores=random.choice(Colores)
    self.Root2.config(bg=random_colores)
    self.Frame2.config(bg=random_colores)
    self.Root2.after(1000, self.CambioColor)
    self.Frame2.after(1000, self.CambioColor)
M=Ventanas()
M.Ventana()
```

Answer (score 0):

Funciona perfectamente si solamente invocas al método `after` una vez (sobre `self.Root2` o sobre `self.Frame2`):

```py
def CambioColor(self):
    Colores=["Blue", "Red", "Pink", "Orange", "Yellow", "Purple", "Brown", "Lime", "White", "Cyan"]
    random_colores=random.choice(Colores)
    self.Root2.config(bg=random_colores)
    self.Frame2.config(bg=random_colores)
    self.Root2.after(1000, self.CambioColor)
    #self.Frame2.after(1000, self.CambioColor)
```

**NOTA:** Estás invocando al método `CambioColor` recursivamente, una vez por segundo. Cada vez que invocas a este método estás creando una nueva lista local de la función llamada `Colores`. Puesto que la lista nunca cambia sería mas óptimo que fuese una tupla. Mejor aun si fuese un atributo de clase:

```py
class Ventanas:

    Colores=("Blue", "Red", "Pink", "Orange", "Yellow", "Purple", "Brown", "Lime", "White", "Cyan")

    # ...

    def CambioColor(self):
        random_colores=random.choice(self.Colores)
        self.Root2.config(bg=random_colores)
        self.Frame2.config(bg=random_colores)
        self.Root2.after(1000, self.CambioColor)
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta, aplicare tus cambios

Comment: No hay de que amigo! ^^

Comment: Añadí esta función para hacer que el Root y Frame cambien de color de forma distinta añadiendo también otra Tupla con otros colores, parece que ya no se cuelga. Muchas Gracias. https://imgur.com/a/8RBluqk

Comment: Perfecto, comprendiste cual era el error. Mucho ánimo con tus proyectos de programación! :D